# unlock a user in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership, unlock

I want to unlock a user and my code is here:
I set maxInvalidPasswordAttempts in my web.config before

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
        if (user.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LockedAccount");
            user.UnlockUser();
        }
        else
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                      && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

I have an error in the user.UnlockUser(); that says unreachable code detected

Answer (score 2):

***I have an error in the user.UnlockUser(); that says unreachable code detected***

Your code

```
if (user.IsLockedOut)
{
    return RedirectToAction("LockedAccount");
    user.UnlockUser();
}
```

You have used `return` before `user.UnlockUser()` so that function will never be called thus you are getting error.

Change it to

```
if (user.IsLockedOut)
{
    user.UnlockUser();
    return RedirectToAction("LockedAccount");
}
```